# How to Interface onReceive Method

Tags: android, interface

I've set up a class called `NetworkStatus` that monitors the network status of the device. Within `NetworkStatus` I've defined a `BroadcastReceiver` that monitors if there has been a connectivity change, i.e., if the internet has been switched *off* or *on*. I want to 'expose' this method (i.e. `onReceive`) to the activity that instantiated the instance of `NetworkStatus`.

I'm trying to achieve this by setting up an `interface` in the `NetworkStatus` class, but I'm not sure how to call the interface from the `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver` i.e.,

```
public class NetworkStatus {
    public static interface NetworkStatusCallbacks {
        void onReceive();
    }

    public static class ConnectivityChange extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // need to call NetworkStatusCallbacks onReceive here
        }
    }

}
```

Then in the main activity I would do something like,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements NetworkStatus.NetworkStatusCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onReceive() {
      // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate some pointers. Thanks.

**Possible Solution**

Think I have found a solution. As Selvin pointed out, to do this requires the `Activity`. I therefore obtained the `Activity` by casting it from the activity context that is passed to a constructor for the `NetworkStatus` class, i.e., setting a constructor for the class as

```
private static nsc NetworkStatusCallbacks;
public NetworkStatus (Context context) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    nsc = (NetworkStatusCallbacks) activity;
}
```

I can then call the interface from the `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver` as follows:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    nsc.onReceive();
}
```

Comment: short answer is you can't since you dont have instance of MyAcitivity it will be better to store this information in fx database in ConnectivityChange.onRecive and read those values in Activity ...

Comment: Okay. Thanks Selvin. Could I not pass the activity into `NetworkStatus` in a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    public class NetworkStatus {
        public static interface NetworkStatusCallbacks {
            void onReceive();
        }

        private final NetworkStatusCallbacks m_cb;

        NetworkStatus(NetworkStatusCallbacks cb)
        {
          m_cb=cb;
        }

        public static class ConnectivityChange extends BroadcastReceiver {

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // need to call NetworkStatusCallbacks onReceive here
               m_cb.onReceive()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nargis. But I'm getting a compile error, i.e., *variable m_cb might not have been initialized* ?

Comment: @Nargis m_cb should be the field of `ConnectivityChange` not `NetworkStatus` (same as the constructor) ... the only question is if he is setuping BroadcastReceiver  with code or with AndroidManifest.xml ... if in manifest it will not work ...

Comment: Broadcast Receiver was included in Manifest file